# EOFError when communicating between processes using SharedMemoryManager

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The following code communicates a list between processes by using SharedMemoryManager, but I don't know why it causes `EOFError: Ran out of input`

```
from multiprocessing.managers import SharedMemoryManager
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def train(sl, process_name):
    for i in range(100):
        sl[0] = i
        time.sleep(0.2)

def debug3d(cls, process_name):
    for i in range(100):
        print("from", process_name, cls)
        time.sleep(0.2)


class Cls:
    def __init__(self, smm):
        self.smm = smm
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with SharedMemoryManager() as smm:
        sl = smm.ShareableList([1])
        p1 = Process(target=train, args=(sl, "process1"))
        instance = Cls(smm)
        p2 = Process(target=debug3d, args=(instance, "process2"))
        p1.start()
        p2.start() 
        p1.join()
        p2.join()
```

however, when I pass shareableList as a parameter of debug3d, it works without an error

```
from multiprocessing.managers import SharedMemoryManager
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def train(sl, process_name):
    for i in range(100):
        sl[0] = i
        time.sleep(0.2)

def debug3d(sl, process_name):
    user_cls = Cls(sl)
    for i in range(100):
        print("from", process_name, user_cls.smm)
        time.sleep(0.2)


class Cls:
    def __init__(self, smm):
        self.smm = smm
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with SharedMemoryManager() as smm:
        sl = smm.ShareableList([1])
        p1 = Process(target=train, args=(sl, "process1"))
        p2 = Process(target=debug3d, args=(sl, "process2")) # I changed here
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()
```

I can't figure out the difference between two.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Umm... I thought I tried my best to provide a minimum reproducible example. Could you explain what you meant by enough detail?

Comment: Can you please include the entire traceback and what OS this occurs on? Multiprocessing works slightly different across OS', so it might not be reproducible or not clear whether one has reproduced the same issue. (FWIW, I think this is already a nice MRE you have here - probably just no one found the time to debug it yet. An [edit] will also draw new attention to the question.)

Comment: Just a heads up that on MacOS 10.14.6, Python 3.9.5, I get an error in the same case but it's a different error. There's a pickling error in the main process (due to a weakref) and in the child process (due to a missing path).

Comment: Is it intentional that the first code passes the *manager*, whereas the second code just passes the *list*? Changing the first code to use ``instance = Cls(sl)`` makes it work flawlessly.

Comment: @MinsterMiyagi Thank you for your considerable comment. It is not intentional. Passing smm object was an mistake; I should've passed sl. Additionally, I realized that in multiprocessing, the error heavily depending on OS as you mentioned. (Somehow, the first code works perfectly with ubuntu 20.04, python 3.8) I will write the answer for closing this question. Thank you for your help.